# Ways to get cotton

Tags: starbound

As of now, I'm stuck trying to make that Teddy Bear, which requires more cotton than even making a Tungsten set.

I got 2 seeds and waiting them to grow after watering each stage takes **a lot of time**, which makes a bad choice. What can I do to gather all the required cotton to make the teddy bear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently cotton plants are the only viable way to obtain cotton. You also need cotton to craft the tier II armors, so you should get several of them.

When you plant your cotton plants (or any crop, for that matter) outside on a planet with frequent rain you don't need to water them yourself. So you can just go exploring while your farm keeps growing on its own.

Comment: I think soil won't get wet from rain if you are too far away from it.

Comment: What about wild cotton plants? Do they grow at the same rate as crops, or should I destroy these wild plants for seeds and plant them on soil myself?

Comment: @Nakilon They indeed get wet if you're on the planet. If they already were wet and you leave the planet or get back to the ship, they will still grow but it be dry when you get back.

Comment: @Rudey They don't grow. After you harvest they won't grow up again, so it's best to get the seeds and plant yourself.

Comment: @DH. 1) I mean if you are on the another side of planet, if it started and stopped raining and you go back to the farm, I guess you'll see it being dry 2) soil become dry on the moment of plant leveling up in growing, so if smth grew even a bit the soil is now dry 3) and about your answer to Rudey -- what if he use Hoe on the ground under the wild plant? will allow the plant that you didn't plant yourself to grow?

Comment: @Nakilon 1) it will actually wet the dirt, it worked, I tested it last time I played. 2) That's what I said, stay at the same planet, that actually rains often, so it works. 3) using the hoe would first remove the plant, and then tile. I hope this clarifies everything, because this is getting a little too extensive for the comments :)